# When my layermask includes the "Player" layer it breaks

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an enemy in my game that when it sees the player it will start charging its attack then fire, and if it loses tack of the player the attack will slowly decharge. But, the raycast I'm working with only properly collides and finds the position of objects when the "Player" layer is not a part of the layermask list. So if I set the layermask to include objects in the "Player" layer, the raycast stops where it starts.

The object creating the raycast has no collision of any kind. I'm using code I wrote that worded on an earlier script and it word there.

The problem area I've found says the following:

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(firePoint.position, aimDirection, range, layerMaskHit);

if(hit.collider != null)
{
    endPoint = hit.point;
    Vector3 LineRot = aimDirection * Vector3.Distance(firePoint.position, endPoint);
    Debug.DrawRay(firePoint.position, LineRot, Color.green);
```

Comment: I don't see a problem. If the raycast stops when it starts, it means the ray collides with something at that point, and you should be able to find out what that thing is from the return value.